# Incorrect buffer length error

Tags: pi-3, opencv, picamera

I'm trying to do an object detection script and save the results into a csv with tensorflow and opencv.

```
camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT)
    camera.framerate = 10
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT))
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):

        t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

        frame = np.copy(frame1.array)
        frame.setflags(write=1)
        frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

        i=0
        j=0

        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8,
            min_score_thresh=0.40)

        # cv2.putText(frame,"FPS: {0:.2f}".format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),font,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        #cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

        for element in boxes:
            current_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
            for score in scores[i]:
                if score > 0.6:
                    if classes[i][j] in (1,2,3,4,6,7,8):
                        if 'old_class' not in locals() or 'old_element' not in locals():
                            save_picture_and_csv(frame,classes[i][j],node_id,score)

                        elif classes[i][j] != old_class:
                            save_picture_and_csv(frame,classes[i][j],node_id,score)

                        elif not check_coords(element[i], old_element):
                            save_picture_and_csv(frame,classes[i][j],node_id,score)

                        old_class = classes[i][j]
                        old_element = element[i]        
                j=j+1
            i = i+1
        t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
        time1 = (t2-t1)/freq
        frame_rate_calc = 1/time1

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break


    camera.close()
```

And the error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ironeye.py", line 178, in <module>
    for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1710, in capture_continuous
    encoder.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 431, in close
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 419, in stop
    self._close_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 349, in _close_output
    mo.close_stream(output, opened)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 371, in close_stream
    stream.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 238, in flush
    self.array = bytes_to_rgb(self.getvalue(), self.size or self.camera.resolution)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 127, in bytes_to_rgb
    'Incorrect buffer length for resolution %dx%d' % (width, height))
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 640x480
```

This is really weird cause was working fine in Raspbian Stretch and I flashed a fresh new SD card with Raspbian Buster and stopped working.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065328/picameravalueerror-incorrect-buffer-length-for-resolution-1920x1080 help?

Comment: Already tried, and nothing